# How do I remove base tags from jQuery mobile scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery Mobile:

- How do I remove the `<base href="">` tags from the page
- How do I disable base href?

Relevant Code:

```
 // Test for dynamic-updating base tag support ( allows us to avoid href,src attr rewriting )
 function baseTagTest() {
     var fauxBase = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname + "ui-dir/",
         base = $("head base"),
         fauxEle = null,
         href = "",
         link, rebase;

     if (!base.length) {
         base = fauxEle = $("<base>", { "href": fauxBase }).appendTo("head");
     } else {
         href = base.attr("href");
     }

     link = $("<a href='testurl' />").prependTo(fakeBody);
     rebase = link[0].href;
     base[0].href = href || location.pathname;

     if (fauxEle) {
         fauxEle.remove();
     }
     return rebase.indexOf(fauxBase) === 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The base element is a key ingredient to jQuery mobile's navigation model, so much that when jQuery mobile sites are loaded in browsers that cannot dynamically update the base element, it prepends the url with the base.

Two suggestions to address your need:

1. Use absolute file paths instead of relative
2. Use the [jQuery Mobile Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) and customize the modules you need for your jQuery Mobile application.  My initial guess is that you would want to exclude the navigation module to remove the base element functionality.